# How to get days between two dates in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I want to get days between two dates in Flutter. as follows：

```dart
List<DateTime> getDays({DateTime start, DateTime end}) {
    // TODO ...
}

List<DateTime> days = getDays(
    start: DateTime.parse('2021-10-25 12:00:00'),
    end: DateTime.parse('2021-10-28 12:00:00'),
);
```

The data in the returned list is as follows:

```dart
[
 DateTime(), // 2021-10-25 12:00:00
 DateTime(), // 2021-10-26 12:00:00
 DateTime(), // 2021-10-27 12:00:00
]
```

How to implement the `getDays` method. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to implement it. There's already one that does this.

```
void main() {

  List<DateTime> getDays({
    required DateTime start,
    required DateTime end
  }) {
    final days = end.difference(start).inDays;

    return [
      for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) 
        start.add(Duration(days: i))
      ];
  }

  List<DateTime> days = getDays(
    start: DateTime.parse('2021-10-25 12:00:00'),
    end: DateTime.parse('2021-10-28 12:00:00'),
  );

  print(days);

  // [
  //  2021-10-25 12:00:00.000, 
  //  2021-10-26 12:00:00.000, 
  //  2021-10-27 12:00:00.000
  // ]
}
```

Comment: OP wants a `List<DateTime>` (not `int`) to be returned

Comment: oooooooh I see, I thought it was an error... I'll edit it, thanks

Comment: @pskink There. Thanks

Comment: Note that this can give unexpected results across DST changes.  If you want to avoid that, use UTC.